# How do I stub a global variable that acts like a hash in Rspec?

Tags: rspec

I have code in a service that looks like this:

```
$flipper[:fall_season].enabled?
```

How does one stub that in an RSpec test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$flipper = {} # or defined some other place.....
fall_session = double
allow(fall_session).to receive(:enabled?).and_return(true)
allow($flipper).to receive(:[]).with(:fall_session).and_return(fall_session)

expect($flipper[:fall_session].enabled?).to be(true)
```